# cannot resolve the collation conflict between latin1_general_ci_as and sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as in the union operation

Tags: sql, collation

```
SELECT   
  f.feature_id,
  f.site_code,
  f.plot_number,
  'ID Error - 7th and 8th characters of ID do not match the Island of the selected Structure, expected value: ' + f.ward_code as message_text,
  'Y' as IsError
FROM feature f
  inner join feature_type ft on f.feature_type_code = ft.feature_type_code AND ft.feature_group_code IN ('FC')
WHERE f.ward_code <> RIGHT(LEFT(f.feature_id, 8),2)

union

SELECT  
  f.feature_id,
  f.site_code,        
  f.plot_number,
  'ID Error - Engineering District do not match the Region of the selected    Structure, expected value: '+ laa.region as message_text,
  'Y' as IsError
FROM feature f
  inner join feature_type ft on f.feature_type_code = ft.feature_type_code AND ft.feature_group_code IN ('FC')
  inner join loc_ase.loc_db.dbo.loc_admin_area laa on f.contract_area_code = laa.contract_area_code 
WHERE f.[area_code] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS <> laa.[region] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 1):

You should select `VARCHAR` fields in one of the collations to avoid this error. An example:

```
CREATE TABLE #t1(some_text NVARCHAR(512) COLLATE latin1_general_ci_as);
CREATE TABLE #t2(other_text NVARCHAR(512) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as);

SELECT some_text FROM #t1
UNION
SELECT other_text COLLATE latin1_general_ci_as FROM #t2

DROP TABLE #t1;
DROP TABLE #t2;
```

This will not result in collation errors. Apply this way of working to your query.

Comment: As usual I always expect all `sql`-tagged questions appearing in my frontpage are for `sql-server` (ignored tags and all that). This answer reflects how this should be done in SQL Server.